# Serialize a part of an object to json

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class that looks like this in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject> MyObjectLists { get; set; }
}
```

and i just want to serialize to JSON **a part** of that object : just **Id**, **Description** and **Location** properties so that the resulted JSON will look like this :

```
{
    "Id": "theID",
    "Description": "the description",
    "Location": "the location"
}
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using JSON.Net you can add a method:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeMyObjectList()
{
    return false;
}
```

Alternately you can use `JsonIgnore` above the properties you don't want to serialize but that will also stop them from being deserialized.

EDIT:

JSON.Net automatically looks for a method with signature `public bool ShouldSerializeProperty()` and uses that as logic for whether it should serialize a particular property. Here is the documentation for that:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thing = new MyClass
    {
        Id = "ID",
        Description = "Description",
        Location = "Location",
        MyObjectLists = new List<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject { Name = "Name1" },
            new MyObject { Name = "Name2" }
        }
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.Read();
}

class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<MyObject> MyObjectLists { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeMyObjectLists()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON output looks like this: `{"Id":"ID","Description":"Description","Location":"Location"}`

Comment: But how to use that function with the serialization ? should i put is as an argument or what ?

Comment: You don't actually have to do anything with it. Json.Net automatically looks for methods with signature `bool ShouldSerailizePropertyName` and uses those when serializing. I'll add code for an example.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Newtonsoft Json.NET` then you can apply `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the `MyObjectLists` property.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<MyObject> MyObjectLists { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

Yes, you can avoid `[JsonIgnore]` attribute. You may write a custom `JsonConverter`.

See example here: [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

You can also use the `ShouldSerialize` solution from @GBreen12.